# Swift Compilation - error emitting MetaData of Class

Tags: ios, swift, game-engine

```
import Foundation

class ObjectPool <T:GameEntity> : NSObject
{
    var counter = 0
    let objects:T[]


    init( poolCapacity:Int )
    {
        objects = Array<T>(count: poolCapacity, repeatedValue: T())
        super.init()
    }

    func getObject() -> T?
    {

        if let counterObject = self.objects[counter] as T? {
            if !counterObject.alive {
                counter++
                return counterObject
            }
        }

        for (index, poolable) in enumerate(self.objects) {
            if !poolable.alive {
                counter = index + 1

                poolable.alive = true
                return poolable
            }
        }

        NSException(name: "Empty Pool", reason: "Trying to get an object from a pool that is drained", userInfo: nil).raise()

        return nil
    }

    func returnObject( pooledObject:T )
    {
        pooledObject.alive = false
    }

    func eachAlive ( lamda:(T -> Void) )
    {
        for poolable in self.objects {
            if poolable.alive {
                lamda(poolable)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I have written some code to create an Object Pool in Swift. The 'GameEntity' is just a class that subclasses SKSpriteNode and has a 'alive' property. I'm wondering if there are any big problems in the code that I have written, or whether this is a compiler problem. The compiler error is below:

```
1.  While emitting IR for source file /Users/joey.clover/Documents/Personal Projects/Flappy Bird/Flappy Bird/Utils/ObjectPool.swift
2.  While emitting class metadata for 'ObjectPool' at /Users/joey.clover/Documents/Personal Projects/Flappy Bird/Flappy Bird/Utils/ObjectPool.swift:11:1
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

Thanks, Joey.

Comment: This isn't a compiler error so much as the compiler crashing.  You should open a radar with the code and the crash log.

Comment: How do I open a radar?

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Did you import sprike kit to your project?

Comment: Thanks Brian, and Gokhan, I import it in the GameEntity class if that means anything?

Comment: Which ios version are you trying to simulate? Can you run the code successfully or does it fail?

Comment: Any other frameworks are you using?

Comment: Not using any other framework, no :/

Comment: You might try *not* subclassing from NSObject. I encountered this same crash, and that fixed it.

Comment: I'm getting this same error in Xcode 6.3. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I never did find one, no :(